# Android LinearLayout fill with buttons

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to fill the LinearLayout with buttons.

The way I want it, is by filling the top of the screen first until the end of the line then if there is no space left, go to the next line and so on, like in the below picture.

[image]

I tried this code but it fill the screen vertically

```
    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear_layout_tags);
    //layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    layout.setGravity(Gravity.FILL);
    Button bt1 = new Button(this);
    bt1.setText("A Button");
    bt1.setLayoutParams(new ActionBar.LayoutParams(ActionBar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ActionBar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    layout.addView(bt1);
```

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or you're looking for FlowLayout for Android. Some implementations are here.

https://github.com/ApmeM/android-flowlayout

https://github.com/blazsolar/FlowLayout

Comment: Thanks, this is definitely the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is a [FlexboxLayout](https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout).

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for one of this?

[MultiTextTagView](https://github.com/loopeer/MultiTextTagView)
[TokenAutoComplete](https://github.com/splitwise/TokenAutoComplete)
[Android Chips](https://github.com/klinker41/android-chips)
[AndroidTagView](https://github.com/whilu/AndroidTagView)
[Chips Android](https://github.com/eyeem/chips-android)

Comment: AndroidTagView was the best for me, but i didn't find the method that can change tags colors, do you know it ?

Comment: you can find it in description of library, here is the field name `tag_background_color` check [this](https://github.com/whilu/AndroidTagView#attributes)

Comment: I find that one but i need to do it programmatically, for example when i click a tag it's background color change.